# Hiding property setters by class in Swift

Tags: swift

I would like to hide some property setters and initializers on my Swift model objects. These are reference data that the server provides, and under no circumstances should they be created or modified by the application. This is simple enough in Swift.

However, there is application in my project (a separate target) that needs to break this rule. It is a tool I use to populate the data in bulk, so of course needs to be able to initialize new model objects and set their properties.

What are my options for accomplishing this? I would rather not use a completely new project since it will mean a lot of code duplication. Is there some language-level way to keep this mutability hidden from one application but available to another?

Comment: The model objects must have an init method that let you set all the properties otherwise how are they created in the first place?

Comment: Yes, good point. I should have been clearer about that. The model objects are all subclasses, in this case of PFObject since. I am using the sparse SDK. The parent has an initializer but the subclasses hide it from my application. As a result the properties are necessarily optionals. It’s a little convoluted but probably not something I can avoid mentioning. Perhaps I will update the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare a property with the `let` keyword. It can then only be set in the `init` of the type.

You can also declare a private setter to make the property readonly from the caller of the type but read/write inside the type

```swift
struct Foo {
  private(set) var bar: Bool = true

  func toggle() {
    bar.toggle()
  }
}

var foo = Foo()

let barState = foo.bar // This works
foo.toggle() // This works too
foo.bar.toggle() // This will make a compile time error
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need access outside the type from some classes but not others.